# How to handle the Action.submit on an adaptive card with LUIS

Tags: node.js, botframework, adaptive-cards

How do we do the handle Action.submit when we use the LUIS recognizer in our bot using MS BotFramework?

```
var recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer(config.LUIS_MODEL_URL);
bot.recognizer(recognizer);

bot.dialog('toolAccess', [
    function (session,args,next) {

           const msg = new builder.Message(session)
                      .addAttachment({
            //adaptive card body here with Action.submit buttons...
           });
           session.send(msg);
    }
]).triggerAction({ matches : 'toolAccess'});
//toolAccess is an intent in my LUIS app.
```

My actions for the adaptive card are:

```
"actions": [
                {
                    "type": "Action.Submit",
                    "data": {
                            "type": "okProfileSelection"
                    },
                    "title": "OK"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Action.Submit",
                    "data": {
                            "type": "cancelProfileSelection"
                    },
                    "title": "Cancel"
                }
            ]
```

So the question is how do I handle these OK and Cancel buttons? Should I add another dialog? If so, what should the triggerAction be?

Answer (score 0):

When you setup your bot, use a default handler like this:

```
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, function (session) {

    if (session.message && session.message.value) {
        // A Card's Submit Action obj was received
        processSubmitAction(session, session.message.value);
        return;
    }

    // Display Welcome card with Hotels and Flights search options
    // load Adaptive Card from JSON file
    var card = require('./card-hotels-flights-search.json');

    // send the card with form 
    var msg = new builder.Message(session).addAttachment(card);
    session.send(msg);
});
```

For a complete working example check out: [BotBuilder-Samples/Node/cards-AdaptiveCards](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/cards-AdaptiveCards)

Comment: the example you are referring to does not use a LUIS recognizer. That is why the constructor callback which handles the session.message can be used there: `var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, function (session) {...}` But in a bot where LUIS is used, i cannot make it capture a Action.submit button

Comment: [continued] in a bot where a LUIS recognizer is used, Action.submit button is always trying to route to a dialog. The problem is which one? How do we make the bot take a certain dialog route?
It is for sure that `var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, function (session) {...}` never runs in a bot with LUIS.

Comment: [Update] : The problem was that I was using `console.log` inside this default handler which was making it behave strangely, even crash in some cases. I have not investigated yet.